# Choosing IR emitter and receiver for data transfer

Tags: integrated-circuit, infrared

I want to transfer data from a not far distance using infrared. There will be 2 separate PCBs and they will provide data transfer to each other. For this, I will use one of the MCP2120 or MCP2122 ENDEC ICs.

[MCP2120 Datasheet](https://www.mouser.com.tr/datasheet/2/268/21618a-74706.pdf)

[MCP2122 Datasheet](https://www.mouser.com.tr/datasheet/2/268/21894c-41674.pdf)

But I don't know how to choose IR emitter and receiver. Are all IR emitters and receivers compatible with each other? What parameters should I pay attention to when choosing? I will use 2 IR emitters and 2 IR receivers in total.

Can LTE-4206 and SFH-229FA be used together?

Also do I need a transistor for this process? Can I connect the IR emitter and receiver directly to the ENDEC IC?

Comment: Define your expecttions, volume cost, , range, beam half-angle, power, bit rate, protocol?   Don't ask "do I need a transistor" until you can specify these

Comment: You are being inefficient and cost-unwise to use a discrete design  RPM841-H16 https://www.digipart.com/part/RPM841-H1 Unless you need a certain IR beam

Comment: Sure they can be used together, but to do what, how far, how fast, how cheap? how many, 20 to 50 mA

Answer (score 1):

The chips are just encoders and decoders for IrDA protocol and meant to be used with IrDA optical transceiver modules.

The chips just have digital input and digital output, so you can't connect an IR LED and IR photodiode directly to the chips, you need circuitry to drive the LED from digital output and you need photodiode amplifier with data slicer etc to convert optical signal to digital input.

IrDA transceivers are standardized so any transceiver should work with any other transceiver.

Depending on what devices you need to make communicate together, you may not even need the chips.

Comment: I will use STM32L073 and it has IrDA SIR ENDEC block. But I will use ENDEC IC as I don't want to mess with code. Thanks for the reply, I will research the data slicer circuit and would be happy if you could suggest any source about circuit that I need

Comment: My suggestion is, if you use a MCU with IrDA built in, using external chips is waste of time and money, and forget making the slicer yourself because that's why IrDA transceiver modules exist.

Comment: If you are talking about a component like TFDU4101-TR3, I prefer to build the slicer circuit myself. Because IrDA transceivers are over $5

Comment: @harmonica Your discrete IR LED and IR photodiode are almost $2, do you think you can design a discrete transceiver that actually works with parts that cost less than an IrDA module?

Comment: Rohm's IRDA IC's are $3 but non-stocked unless you order direct from Chinese Disti's < $1 in volume

Comment: @Justme I will check again

Answer (score 1):

IR Stands for Infra-Red, which is basically ~700nm up to anything beyond.

Usually IR transmitter for remote like that will be in the 700-1000nm range as Leds / Receivers becomes expensive beyond that range.

The most important is making sure that the emission wavelength is within the receiver spectral sensitivity.

The best sensitivity will also be achieved if the emission is entirely within the sensitivity range, which is the case for the two you mentionned.

LTE4206

[image]

SFH-229FA:

[image]

So those two devices would be compatible.

**Improving SNR**

Some other factor may also be to be considered which is reliance to unwanted signal. The SFH-229FA has a very wide sensitivity from 700 to ~1000nm which means it will be sensitive of background light.

A photodiode with a narrower spectral sensitivity focused on the peak of the emitter would improve the robustness of the system, adding a filter can achieve the same.

**Other**

Other point to consider obviously is the emission power, sensitivity, angle of emission, angular sensitivity.